# CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync in native C++

Tags: c++, push-notification, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use windows push notifications in native C++ code. But I struggle with implementation. I'm calling `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync` but it returns
`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND) : Element not found.`

My OS is Win10 and I use Visual Studio 2015.

Here is my code:

```
#include <wrl.h>
#include <windows.networking.pushnotifications.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")

using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Networking::PushNotifications;
using namespace concurrency;

int main(char* argv[], int argc)
{
    RoInitializeWrapper init(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if ( FAILED(init) )
        return 0;

    ComPtr<IPushNotificationChannelManagerStatics> channelManager;
    HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(L"Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager").Get(), &channelManager);

    if ( FAILED(hr) )
        return 0;

    IAsyncOperation<PushNotificationChannel*>* asyncOp;
    hr = channelManager->CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync(&asyncOp); // return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND)

    if ( FAILED(hr) )
        return 0;

    // create task to obtain uri from asyncOp

    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand it is pretty straightforward in WinRT.

```
namespace WnsPushAPI
{
    public ref class WnsWrapper sealed
    {
    public:

        void ObtainUri()
        {
            IAsyncOperation<PushNotificationChannel^>^ channelOperation = PushNotificationChannelManager::CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
            auto channelTask = create_task(channelOperation);
            channelTask.then([this](PushNotificationChannel^ channel) {
                // ... Save URI for latter use. channel->Uri->Data()
                channel->PushNotificationReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<PushNotificationChannel^, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs^>(this, &WnsWrapper::OnNotify);
            }, task_continuation_context::use_current());
        }

        void OnNotify(PushNotificationChannel^ sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs^ e)
        {
            // do something
        };
    };
}
```

I also checked generated code with `/d1ZWtokens` compiler switch but I didn't find anything useful.
Documentation for push notification for native C++ is really poorly written and I couldn't find and example in native C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay. The problem lies in the fact that you can only register for push notifications from Windows Store applications. You cannot do that from desktop applications. The error comes from the fact that the system cannot find your AppX package identity.

Comment: So there must be way how to set AppX identity for my desktop app. When I create UWP app with C++/CX then I can see this identity in `Package.appxmanifest`. I have to find out how to move this identity to my app. At the end C++/CX is also only .exe file but somehow it is registered or contains valid identity for win store.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND)` error while trying to use WNS from my desktop app. Just in case anyone also faces this issue I'd like to mention `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync` works fine from Desktop Bridge. Here is the code that I used. Note it is `winrt` based, and I think `WRL` based code also would work without any problem, just need to wrap desktop app with Desktop Bridge.

```
winrt::init_apartment();
PushNotificationChannelManagerForUser manager = PushNotificationChannelManager::GetDefault();
IAsyncOperation<PushNotificationChannel> async = manager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

async.Completed([](auto && result, auto && status) {
    auto channel = result.GetResults();
});
```