# Call C++CX from native C++ code

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I need to combine native C++ code with C++CX code.
Our product is mainly in native C++ and I need access win10 feature (PushNotifications). But this feature is written in WinRT so it is accessible from C++CX, C#, ... but not directly from C++.

Yes I know that now you will tell me that it is possible because C++CX is at the end compiled as native code. In this case check my previous post.[CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync in native C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343512/createpushnotificationchannelforapplicationasync-in-native-c)

So I am looking for another options. I would like to create C++CX DLL and then load it into C++ native application. But I also failed because I wasn't able to use native callback in C++CX class. I need to register callback or interface which will be triggered when notification comes. But I couldn't register it. Because native pointer can not be part of public interface of C++CX class.

**I Have two questions:**

1. How I can use native pointer in C++CX class?
2. Is there another approach which I can use to access this WinRT COM from native C++ ?

**UPDATE:**
I found out how to fix compiler error but it is still not working.
Declare member function which uses native pointer as private and than declare `friend` function which could access this private member.

Now I'm getting error: `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND) : Element not found.` which is same as in my native approach.

Maybe problem is that my app is not associated with win store application. But I created UWP application and I didn't associate it with win store and it works. So I really don't know what could be problem.

Here is simplified code:

*header (declaration of DLL interface)*

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class IEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual void UriRefreshAsync(std::wstring&& uri) = 0;
    virtual void OnNotify(std::wstring&& content) = 0;
};

extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void RegisterEventHandler(IEventHandler* handler);
}
```

*definition (DLL definition compiled with `/ZW`)*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <collection.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wrl/wrappers/corewrappers.h>
#include "wns.h"

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Networking::PushNotifications;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace concurrency;

namespace WnsPushAPI
{
public ref class WnsWrapper sealed
{
public:
    WnsWrapper() : winRT(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED) {};

    static WnsWrapper^ Instance() { return singleton ? singleton : singleton = ref new WnsWrapper(); }

    void ObtainUri()
    {
        IAsyncOperation<PushNotificationChannel^>^ channelOperation = PushNotificationChannelManager::CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
        auto channelTask = create_task(channelOperation);
        channelTask.then([this](PushNotificationChannel^ channel) {
            eventHandler->UriRefreshAsync(std::wstring(channel->Uri->Data()));
            channel->PushNotificationReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<PushNotificationChannel^, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs^>(this, &WnsWrapper::OnNotify);
        }, task_continuation_context::use_current());
    }

    void OnNotify(PushNotificationChannel^ sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        if ( e->NotificationType == PushNotificationType::Raw )
        {
            eventHandler->OnNotify(std::wstring(e->RawNotification->Content->Data()));
        }
        e->Cancel = true;
    };
private:

    void RegisterEventHandler(IEventHandler* handler) { eventHandler = handler; };

    friend void ::RegisterEventHandler(IEventHandler* handler);

    RoInitializeWrapper winRT;
    IEventHandler* eventHandler = nullptr;
    std::wstring uri;
    static WnsWrapper^ singleton;
};

WnsWrapper^ WnsWrapper::singleton = nullptr;
}

void RegisterEventHandler(IEventHandler* handler)
{
    WnsPushAPI::WnsWrapper::Instance()->RegisterEventHandler(handler);
}

void GetUriAsync()
{
    WnsPushAPI::WnsWrapper::Instance()->ObtainUri();
}
```

*Main (native C++ applicaton)*

```
#include "../wns/wns.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Events : public IEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual void UriRefreshAsync(std::wstring&& uri) 
    {
        wcout << uri << endl;
    };

    virtual void OnNotify(std::wstring&& content) { /*trigger notify*/ };
};

int main(char* argv[], int argc)
{
    Events events;
    RegisterEventHandler(&events);
    GetUriAsync();

    Sleep(100*1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++/CX is merely a language extension, that allows to more easily access WinRT types. They are still COM objects, and can be accessed from native C++ like any other COM object. You can use [WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx) to make this easier, or go with [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) (a standard C++ language projection for the Windows Runtime, currently only available as a preview).

Comment: I know about this but I struggled to do it in [native code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343512/createpushnotificationchannelforapplicationasync-in-native-c) so I'm trying different approach.

Comment: C++/WinRT *is* native, standard C++ code. There is no compiler-generated code, as is the case with C++/CX.

Comment: I got further but again struggle with error `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND) : Element not found.`

Comment: Note you can use `internal` instead of the `private` / `friend` hack if you want to keep things out of the WinRT interface. That said, what line gives you the error? What kind of project is your main app? Is it a UWP app or a console EXE (in which case, is it wrapped in an AppX and installed correctly)?

Comment: I'll try it with `internal`. Error is from `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()`. Main is Win32 console EXE. DLL was also created as win32 dll but with support for C++CX. What it means installed correctly?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT `internal` keyword helped me to get rid off compiler error but I still get error from `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()`. What did you mean by "installed correctly"? Are there another prerequisites which I need to do?

Comment: Did you create an AppX package and install it? You can't just run the EXE if you want to use push notifications.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I'll try it but there has to be some underline layer which provide this registration. There is `Package.appxmanifest` with identity and this is probably somehow registered into my system so that latter I can receive push notifications. I'm just building component for our product and it won't be standalone AppX.

Comment: You can use the MakeAppx.exe tool to create an app package (see [Create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool)). There are a number of [AppxCmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/appx/index) for PowerShell to install and manage packages in your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can enable C++ CX support for a non WinRT Application. To do that, go to properties->C/C++ and select Consume Windows Runtime Extensions to Yes (/ZW).